# Apple Script to Send Text when Ladiocast Disconnected and reconnects

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have a script that restarts the App 'Ladiocast' when it stops.

**This Works**

on diswitherror(1)
repeat 6000 times
delay 10
try
tell application "LadioCast" to connect 1
return
end try
end repeat
end diswitherror

**I created this and it works**

tell application "Messages" to send "Ladiocast Stream disconnected" to buddy "xxx-xxx-xxxx" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage

**However when I add them together it does not.**

on diswitherror(1)
tell application "Messages" to send "Ladiocast Stream disconnected" to buddy "xxx-xxx-xxxx" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)
repeat 6000 times
delay 10
try
tell application "LadioCast" to connect 1
return
end try
end repeat
tell application "Messages" to send "Ladiocast Stream Connected" to buddy "xxx-xxx-xxxx" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)
end diswitherror

I don't know where to go next!